# Fully featured REST server with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, rest

Is possible to create a fully-featured REST server with Ruby (not Rails)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

You'll need to implement all the rest stuff yourself and there's no good reason to do all the hard work when it's already done for you.

If you think Rails is too heavy for what you're doing then maybe [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/) would be better for you.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, use sinatra.

http://www.sinatrarb.com/

Answer (score 8):

Yes, see [Grape](https://github.com/intridea/grape) for a good example.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are no limitations. REST is a language-agnostic architectural style. The language you choose to implement your interface doesn't affect the final result.

Of course, instead of starting from scratch, you might want to use an existing Ruby framework like [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/). But if you want the full control of your request at a very low level, [Rack](http://rack.rubyforge.org/) itself is a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

of course, but i'd recommend considering using another web framework, e.g. [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/) if you don't want to bloat your app with a full featured Rails stack.